# jQuery autocomplete category location

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I use to have this:

```
$( "#glavnotursene" ).autocomplete({
    delay: 0,
    source: 'extrastuff.php?glavnotursene',
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        window.location = 'maps.php?id. ' + ui.item.nomer;
    }
});
```

And it works perfectly. When the items popup and I click them I get redirected to maps.php
I decided to use categories as well so I did it like this:

```
    $.widget( "custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
            _renderMenu: function( ul, items ) {
                var self = this,
                    currentCategory = "";
                $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
                    if ( item.category != currentCategory ) {
                        ul.append( "<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>" );
                        currentCategory = item.category;
                    }
                    self._renderItem( ul, item );
                });
            }
        });

$( "#glavnotursene" ).catcomplete({
        delay: 0,
        source: 'extrastuff.php?glavnotursene',
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            window.location = 'maps.php?id. ' + ui.item.nomer;
        }
    });
```

and the select wouldn't work anymore so people don't get redirected.

I'm using:

- jQuery UI - v1.10.0
- jQuery v1.9.1

Answer (score 1):

Try to do it in this way:

```
$( "#glavnotursene" ).autocomplete({
   delay: 0,
   source: 'extrastuff.php?glavnotursene',
   select: function( event, ui ) {
       window.location = 'maps.php?id. ' + ui.item.nomer;
   }
}).data("autocomplete")._renderMenu = function(ul, items) {
  var self = this, currentCategory = "";
  $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
     if ( item.category != currentCategory ) {
        ul.append( "<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>" );
        currentCategory = item.category;
     }
     self._renderItem( ul, item );
  });
};
```

If it works, it will be only for `$('#glavnotursene')`. Some way to make it general is assign it to an external function:

```
function my_autocomplete(ul, items, self){
  var currentCategory = "";
  $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
     if ( item.category != currentCategory ) {
        ul.append( "<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>" );
        currentCategory = item.category;
     }
     self._renderItem( ul, item );
  });
}

$( "#glavnotursene" ).catcomplete({
   delay: 0,
   source: 'extrastuff.php?glavnotursene',
   select: function( event, ui ) {
       window.location = 'maps.php?id. ' + ui.item.nomer;
   }
}).data("autocomplete")._renderMenu = function(ul, items) {
  my_autocomplete(ul, items, this);
};
```

I didn't check if this work, but I hope it will.